# Generating correlated data based on dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, correlation

```
Total.Volume
      <dbl>
 1         448.
 2         411.
 3         584.
 4         463.
 5         482.
 6         442.
 7         440.
 8         563.
 9         462.
10         451.
```

this is my sales_data and I ll run regression(Marketing Mix Modelling) techiques but I dont have any media variable that I could use.So I wonder if I can generate correlated 3 different variable like tv spends, digital spends and Radio Spends with my sales data that should consider my sales data pattern, seasonality and trend

Is there any package or way to do it with R?